# Can I create a sidebar link via REST?

Tags: rest, bitbucket, sidebar

I can create repos in BitBucket server (on-premises) using the REST API but I would like to add a sidebar link using REST as well. Does anyone know how to craete a sidebar link for a repo using REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it. Just send this JSON:

{"url":"http://www.stackoverflow","label":"StackOverflow"}

To this URL as a POST:

http://bb.mydomain.com:7990/rest/repository-shortcuts/latest/projects/{project}/repos/{slug}/shortcuts