# BitBucket API call to get shortcuts details in a repo

Tags: bitbucket-api

For a repo in bitbucket in the left side menu option we can see source, commit, branch, pull request etc. Like wise there is shortcuts option available in my company domain.
I want to know the shortcuts details in it. Is there any API call for that available which I can use? I looked in https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#authentication but was not able to find the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a GET request to

```
https://<your_bitbucket_url>:<your_bitbucket_port>/rest/repository-shortcuts/latest/projects/{project}/repos/{slug}/shortcuts
```

endpoint might help you.

Inspired by [Can I create a sidebar link via REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657224/can-i-create-a-sidebar-link-via-rest)